# Как избавиться от пустой полосы внизу?

Tags: html, css, html5, адаптивная-верстка

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://oboi-colibri.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/rozovyi.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

Почему div не сжимается под содержимое?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что img выравнивается по базовой линии текста, а там до низа есть запас на случай букв с хвостами (например, `у`, `р` и `j`). Исправляется либо изменением вертикального выравнивания, либо превращением в блок.

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://oboi-colibri.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/rozovyi.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://oboi-colibri.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/rozovyi.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

Comment: Опередил. =) Плюсану.